# IDE don't see all the functions

Tags: python, eclipse, pyscripter

i'm using Elcipse+PyDev and Pyscripter sometimes for Python 2.7
Yesterday i installed PyTables from compiled binaries and :

```
import tables
h5f = tables.openFile(r'D:\sample.h5','w')
h5f.createGroup('/','Box')
h5f.
```

So, when I type "h5f." IDE don't show me all the methods, only a few!
Can't do anything with It, installed PyTables few times,same result...
Method h5f.CreateGroup() works perfectly, but IDE dont see it so don't display it in drop-down list! Eclipse and Python both behave same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with **Pydev and Eclipse** is that when you install a new package or library and if you want to use the auto-complete with it, you will have to recreate the **system PYTHONPATH** in eclipse.

For that go to: **Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreted Python** and in the tab **libraries**, in **System PYTHONPATH** you will not see your new installed library because **pydev** just do a copy of the **PYTHONPATH** the first time that you have configured and now each time you installed a new package you will have to resynchronize **pydev** with the new **PYTHONPATH**.

So to resynchronize you will have to click on the button **Apply** so that eclipse export (again) all the library (between them your new installed one) from **PYTHONPATH** to eclipse.

So now eclipse should know your library and you should work with it just fine.

Hope this will help :)